# Multiple users writing to one Samba mount point in OSX

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, samba, mount

I have an OSX box containing a script which writes a unique file to a Samba share.  The first part of the script mounts the share.

On the machine are 2 users- UserA and UserB.  Each requires to run this script at any given time *however* only the user who mounted the share is able to write to it.  I really need both users to have `rwx` access.

Here is what I have tried:

- Mounting then `chmod`'ing the mountpoint (no effect- overruled by Samba server?)
- `chmod`'ing the mountpoint then mounting (same as above)
- `sudo mount_smbfs`

Both users have admin privileges.  Ideally a solution would be executable by one of the users (contained in the script) and not rely on mounting at machine boot time.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the flags -f *mode* and -d *mode* for this. Note that you *cannot* grant more rights than the server allows.

But mount_smbfs *should* by default at least grant the rights set on the mount path, so it seems your share is locked down a bit too much on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I barely remember there must be guest account configuration in samba server. If you change guest user name as `nobody` and guest user group as `nogroup` your problem might be solved.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a limitation in the Mac OS X SMB client. It's setting up the connection to the server as one of the users, then keeps that connection open and uses it for the second two.

Have you tried running the script on two separate machines, and seeing if that works?